# What is bias in linear regression using NN

Tags: neural-networks, linear-model

I am new in Deep learning. And was implementing linear regression NN from scratch

I have seen

```
y = X*W +b
```

so i believe bias is for per node. Like layer haveing 4 node then number of biases will be 4. Per according to this formula it saying bias is for per layer. And all the nodes have that same bias
Is that correct ?

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178835/bias-input-in-neural-network and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/447528/how-to-understand-the-weights-and-bias etc: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bneural-networks%5D+bias+

Comment: @Sycorax No. bcoze in this link https://medium.com/@lankinen/fast-ai-lesson-8-notes-part-2-v3-8965a6532f51. You can see he is making length 10 array of biases which is number of hidden layers

Comment: I'll say it again, I don't think you're using "layer" in the same way that everyone else does. The post is creating a **single layer** with **10 nodes.** In other words, the reason you're confused appears to be because you're not using terminology correctly.

Comment: @Sycorax Okayyyyyyyyy that is correct